# Pandoc Markdown to docx with title page, TOC and placeholder replacement

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

I am struggling to use pandoc to convert several markdown files to one docx document.

The first page should be a title page, with placeholders, that will be replaced (Title, Project, Author).

The second page shall be the Table of contents and on the third page the content, given by the 1st markdown file should follow, then the 2nd markdown file and so on.

Is this even possible with pandoc?

Any suggestion would be great, I checked stackoverflow and could not find a suitable answer for that issue.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you have some code you could share, that highlights the problem?

Comment: I placed placeholder in the word document like {{Title}}, I also tried [Title] and [[Title] in the docx.
For the Table of Conents, I placed a similar placeholder with the name TOC in the docx.

The first page of the document should be a Titlepage, as desrcibed in my template.docx.

At the top of the markdown file I placed a "header"

```markdown
---
title: Document title
---

# My document

## Subsection 
```

```bash 
pandoc --toc --reference-doc=template.docx input.md -o test.docx
```

The ToC is not a the desired position, the title page is replaced.